# Pose Mode in the "Default View" tab makes my mesh darker not allowing me to select both a bone and the mesh and go into Weight Paint

Tags: weight-painting

Pose Mode in the "Default View" tab makes my mesh darker and unable to be selected. As a result I can't select a desired bone and the mesh and then go into Weight Paint. If I switch to the "UV Editing" tab and try to do the same thing again, it works, I'm able to select a bone and then the mesh and go into Weight Paint. What's the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me in in the UV editor tab too, but I think the correct way is selecting both the mesh and the armature in object mode (the armature must be the active), then go to pose mode and select the bone. It works every time.

Comment: Thanks! I thought maybe there was some setting I didn't have enabled or something like that.